# Rails 4.1 getting rollback while creating an user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails Console:

```
user = HotelUser.create(:email=>'test@gmail.com')
(0.0ms) BEGIN
(0.0ms) ROLLBACK
=> #<HotelUser id: nil, userName: nil, email: "test@gmail.com", address1: nil, address2: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>`
```

I am new in rails.I want to create a user in rails console.But every time i m getting Rollback.Why this is happening.

Comment: Your user is probably not passing validation. Check the model for hints, or inspect it in the console with `user.errors?`. I'd guess you need at least a username & password_digest to be able to save.

Comment: Now i m getting:   user=HotelUser.create(:email=>'ram@gmail.com',:password=>'ram')
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO `hotel_users` (`created_at`, `email`, `password_digest`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-09-24
 06:37:45', 'ram@gmail.com', '$2a$10$FroE5fx.NTKkImi9QqOnf.j5KDwjknyZBaJTS3N2fGn2nsyC1IaIW', '2014-09-24 06:37:45')

Comment: it means you user has been created.

Comment: no not at all,again rollbacked.  Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'password_digest' at row 1: INSERT INTO `hotel_users` (`created_at`, `email`, `password_di
gest`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-09-24 06:37:45', 'ram@gmail.com', '$2a$10$FroE5fx.NTKkImi9QqOnf.j5KDwjknyZBaJTS3N2fGn2nsyC1IaIW
', '2014-09-24 06:37:45')
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mROLLBACK←[0m

Comment: show `app/models/hotel_user.rb` please.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way to check is to use create!

For example:

```
pry(main)> User.create(:fname => "Bob")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<User id: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: nil, fname: "Bob", lname: nil>

pry(main)> User.create!(:fname => "Bob")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
```

The difference between the bang(!) and non-bang is that create! will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can check errors by these codes in Rails console and see your User model to fix it

```
=> user = HotelUser.create(email: 'test@gmail.com')
=> user.errors
```

Comment: I have created an user but not able to login.Started POST "/orders/loginUser" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-24 12:42:08 +0530
Processing by OrdersController#loginUser as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"d+sdUp2PDIhKuS5uj0DLjlqnQrni0YBac4CLe8+1XPI=", "email"=>"ram@gmail.com", "passw
ord"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders/placeOrder
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
t=HotelUser.new 
Then, type this:
t.email="test@Gmail.com"
And the last command, 
t.save

Hope this solves your problem.
The problem with .create was that you didn't pass the other params like created date and updated date and all.